# R - appending rows to data frame in a for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, append

I think this is a silly question but still I need some assistance with syntax as I'm new to R.

I have a blank dataframe with 5 columns. For each row, a pgsql query fetches a row of 5 values that needs to be added to the dataframe on each iteration of the loop.

Exiting_df:

```
Mat  CrA  Cur  Dil  Ccl
NA   Na    Na   Na   Na
```

Each iteration of the loop brings a new dataframe of values from a pgsql query like so:

```
Mat  CrA  Cur  Dil  Ccl
5    13    9   44   2
```

This would get appended to Existing_df like so:
at i = 1:

```
Mat  CrA  Cur  Dil  Ccl
5    13    9   44   2
```

at i=2:

```
Mat  CrA  Cur  Dil  Ccl
5    13   9    44   2
11   1    113  41   11
```

at i=3:

```
Mat  CrA  Cur  Dil  Ccl
5    13   9    44   2
11   1    113  39   11
14   22   79   54   12
```

and so on..

This is the for loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(month_stats))
{
status_counts <- tbl(con_cg_db,sql(
paste("select distinct stagename,
       sum(case when stagename is not null then 1 else 0 end)
       from current_oppty_sf 
       where extract(month from cast(loan_agreement_date__c as date)) = ",i,"
       group by stagename",sep="")
))
status_counts<- t(as.data.frame(status_counts))
### something needs to go here to appropriately combine the data
###frames as I've described in my question
}
```

Sometimes, depending on data, the dataframe bringing values from the pgsql query would have only 3 or 4 columns. In that case, the missing columns need to automatically take up 0 at the respective row & column of the main dataframe.

How do I do this?

Comment: Can you make a simple example in the answer please?

Comment: Consider searching SO first. There are dozens of examples of this. Try `[r] do.call rbind`.

Answer (score 1):

```
require(dplyr)

df<- c() 

for (i in 1:nrow(month_stats))
    {
    status_counts <- tbl(con_cg_db,sql(
    paste("select distinct stagename,
           sum(case when stagename is not null then 1 else 0 end)
           from current_oppty_sf 
           where extract(month from cast(loan_agreement_date__c as date)) = ",i,"
           group by stagename",sep="")
    ))
    status_counts<- t(as.data.frame(status_counts))
    df <- bind_rows(df, status_counts)
    }
```

Instead of zero, this code will give you NA when some value is missing. If you really want zeros, you can insert them after the loop:

```
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
```